# Comparing fit of a Mixed Model to a Fixed Model

Tags: r, regression, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I would like to be able to compare 2 models as is often done as follows:

```
modelA <- lm(Ys ~ X1 + X2 + X3)
modelB <- lm(Ys ~ X1 + X2)
anova(modelA, modelB)
```

but instead of adding or removing a co-variate- my first model is a fixed effects model with a single time point per subject, and my second model is a mixed effects model with several time points per subject and grouped by subjectID:

```
modelA <- lm(Ys ~ X1 + X2 + X3) #e.g. 5 observations/subjects

modelB <- lme(Ys ~ X1 + X2 + X3, random= ~ 1 | subjectID) 
#e.g. same 5 subjects with 3 time points each= 15 observations
```

since chi-square with anova fails in this scenario, how should I compare them. Is there a specific package in `R` I should use? An F-test requires knowing what the d.f. are for a mixed model, which I am unclear on how to calculate.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You tagged the question with the label `lme`. Have you tried applying the function `lmer` within the {lme4} package?